# sending html content in email body(emailBlurb) docusign api

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send html content in my emailBlurb for sending email for document signature by using the following code portion :

> DocumentSignatureRequest documentSignRequest = new documentSignatureRequest();
>
> String blurb = "Testing html email content : `<b>Bold content</b>`";
>
> documentSignRequest.setEmailBlurb(blurb);

---

But the emails I receive from this contain the whole string, instead of using the with the `<b>` instead of bold text. So, I looked at the docs provided by docusign and it indicated for looking at the 'email resource file' in the docusign account. In the file i found the portion :

`<td class="MainStyle" colspan="2">
        <p>[[EmailBlurb]]</p>
        <p>[[RecipientNote]]</p>
</td>`

I am guessing the 'emailBlurb' I am setting is being used simply as a string and thus the html tags are just being displayed as is.

So my question, what are my options with finding a way around this. I know an option is to edit the resource file, but are there any other better options. For instance, any settings or tags in the resource file around the [[EmailBlurb]] or if it can be done from my code? Please help.

Comment: I believe that the ability for the HTML to be honored via the API emailBlurb field, your account needs to have this enabled. This is not a self-service option though - you will need to contact DocuSign support to request it enabled.

Comment: @LuisScott is correct, this should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @LuisScott, thanks. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to insert raw `html` into the notification emails however this is not a self-service option.  You need to reach out to your DocuSign Account Manager or their Support to have the option enabled in your account.